# digital signatures added by Insignia conflicting with PatchCertificates?

Tags: wix, digital-signature

i'm exploring the feature of **digital signatures** in **WiX** context (windows installer **MSI** and windows patch **MSP**).
in my case i'm generating a MSI with a non-embedded "Data1.cab".

to what i have understood it is important to:

- sign any external cabs
- inscribe the MSI with the digital signatures of those cabs
- sign the sign the MSI itself

i'm following the official WiX [insignia documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/insignia.html) for use in visual studio 2015:
so in the *.wixproj file i have added the following section.
additional command line parameters for signtool.exe are omitted for brevity.

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <SignOutput>true</SignOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="SignMsi">
  <Exec Command="signtool.exe sign /a &quot;%(SignMsi.FullPath)&quot;" />
</Target>
<Target Name="SignCabs">
  <Exec Command="signtool.exe sign /a &quot;%(SignCabs.FullPath)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

so far so good.
but i *also* need the `PatchCertificates` for future [UAC patches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372388(v=vs.85).aspx).
so in my *.wxs source file i have:

```
<Product ... >
<Package ... />

<Media Id="1" Cabinet="Data1.cab" EmbedCab="no"/>

<PatchCertificates>
  <DigitalCertificate SourceFile="$(env.MY_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY)/cert256.pem" Id="patchcert"/>
</PatchCertificates>

</product>
```

when i now compile the project in visual studio i always get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\insignia.exe -im C:\src\Test\setup\obj\Release\bin\MyProduct.msi -out C:\src\Test\setup\obj\Release\bin\MyProduct.msi
Insignia.exe(0,0): error INSG0001: Cannot find the requested object.
Done building project "MyInstaller.wixproj" -- FAILED.
```

--

**observation:**

- both features on their own are working fine
- but if i combine the two the compilation fails

**are they incompatible with each other?**

--

additional keywords:

- WiX attributes: DigitalCertificate, PatchCertificates, DigitalSignature
- MSI tables: MsiDigitalCertificate, MsiPatchCertificate, MsiDigitalSignature
- general terms: digital certificate, digital signature, WiX, insignia, votive, public key

--

<strike>update:</strike>
<strike>is it maybe because of this bug (see [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/3340/), see [github](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4055)) (reported in 2013)?</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution.

i was including the certificate in `PEM` format:

```
<PatchCertificates>
  <DigitalCertificate SourceFile="$(env.MY_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY)/cert256.pem" Id="patchcert"/>
</PatchCertificates>
```

but we **must** use a certificate in `DER` format:

```
<PatchCertificates>
  <DigitalCertificate SourceFile="$(env.MY_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY)/cert256_DER.cer" Id="patchcert"/>
</PatchCertificates>
```

also see this related question: [DigitalCertificate (for UAC patches) - format specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157906/digitalcertificate-for-uac-patches-format-specification?noredirect=1&lq=1)

PS:
i just got on the wrong track assuming some *bug* or *incompatibility* because of the specific error message that is not helpful at all.
and also it's strange the error is showing only when combining both of the features.